# Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Integer

Tags: android, alert

I have this t1 as a  text view.
I want to store the value of t1 in  a variable but i am getting "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Integer" error

`Integer res=t1.setText(Integer.toString(result))`;

Comment: What are you aiming to achieve here?

Comment: did you mean string str=t1.getText() to get the value of a text filed of t1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for see the value

```
t1.setText(Integer.toString(result));

String result= t1.getText().toString();
```

and if you want to alert the result:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("result")
    .setMessage("this is your textview value : "+ result)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // you can do what you want when user press yes
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            //  you can do what you want when user press no
        }
     })
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();
```

Comment: @user3437072 if you want to say something else please give details,

Answer (score 7):

This

```
t1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
```

does not return anything

Look at setText @

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: set the message of alert as t1.gettext()

Comment: @user3437072 you can use `String value = t1.getText().toString()`. Use value in alert

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
int value=Integer.valueOf(t1.getText.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get value from t1, so:

> Integer res = Integer.toString(t1.getText().toString());//getting data from textView

only putting data to textView:

> t1.setText(Integer.toString(result)); //it will not return anything

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer.parseInt(); dont forget to include try Catch with numberformatexception.